# What is the "offset was changed from X to 0" error with a KafkaSource in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, offset, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I'm getting the error "offset was changed from X to 0, some data may have been missed" with a KafkaSource in a Spark Structured Streaming application with checkpointing but it doesn't seem to actually cause any problem. I'm trying to figure out what the error actually means.

My setup is as follows.

- I have Kafka (0.10.1.0) running in a docker container, with a named volume mounted on /tmp/kafka-logs so that the logs are kept between restarts.
- I have a Spark Structured Streaming (2.1.1) application in another docker container. The streams consume data from Kafka. They also use checkpointing in locations that are again mounted in a named volume to make sure the metadata is kept between restarts.
- I use a custom sink that implements the [ForeachWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter) interface, which means I have to implement my own log of processed versions so that when everything restarts, I can tell Spark Streaming not to reprocess what has already been processed.

All of this works well, the data gets correctly consumed from Kafka and my custom sink correctly processes it.

Now if I kill the Spark Streaming application, let data in Kafka pile up and then restart Spark Streaming, it will throw the following error, indicating that some data isn't available in Kafka any more

```
ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = cd2b69e1-2f24-439a-bebc-89e343df83a8, runId = d4b3ae65-8cfa-4713-912c-404623710048] terminated with error

Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Partition input.clientes-0's offset
 was changed from 908 to 0, some data may have been missed.

Some data may have been lost because they are not available in Kafka
 any more; either the data was aged out by Kafka or the topic may have 
 been deleted before all the data in the topic was processed. If you 
 don't want your streaming query to fail on such cases, set the source 
 option "failOnDataLoss" to "false".

at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSource$$reportDataLoss(KafkaSource.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$8.apply(KafkaSource.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anonfun$8.apply(KafkaSource.scala:281)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:248)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.getBatch(KafkaSource.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(StreamExecution.scala:452)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.flatMap(StreamProgress.scala:25)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:447)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:177)
```

But after the error gets thrown, I see my streams starting normally. Spark Streaming correctly pushes the data that had piled up in Kafka to my custom sink, with the expected version. My sink then proceeds and correctly processes the new data.

So the error indicates that some data isn't available in Kafka any more, but it still manages to get consumed correctly by Spark Streaming.

If I restart the Spark Streaming application even when no data gets pushed to Kafka, I get the same error again. And if I start pushing new data to Kafka, it will continue to be processed correctly by the system.

Does someone know what could be going on here ? Am I interpreting the error incorrectly ?

Comment: Do you have any Offset handling in your code? This means that your Spark Streaming was reading from Kafka, then you stop and It didn't commit the position or in ZooKeepr or in other stages. When it reach Kafka it asks about position 0 but the ZK knows that you reach the position 908.

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp/kafka-logs` is the logs directory for Kafka where all your offset, topic information is stored. If it is corrupted or some data is deleted, you need to set the option `failOnDataLoss:false` in Kafka options of your `SparkProcessContext` and restart the Spark Job.

```
Option  : failOnDataLoss
Value   : true or false
Default : TRUE
```

Meaning : Whether to fail the query when it's possible that data is lost (e.g., topics are deleted, or offsets are out of range). This may be a false alarm. You can disable it when it doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: That doesn't really help. The cause of the error remains unclear.

Comment: cause of this issue is unknown / undocumented, what I can speculate is the data loss at Kafka or Spark end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug in older versions of the kafka-clients library.

The description of [SPARK-26267](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26267) says

> "Due to [KAFKA-7703- KafkaConsumer.position may return a wrong offset after "seekToEnd" is called](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7703), when the Kafka source tries to get the latest offset, it may get an earliest offset, and then it will reprocess messages that have been processed when it gets the correct latest offset in the next batch."

To summarize, citing the developers who worked on it:

> "this is a know issue in Kafka, please see KAFKA-7703. This is fixed in 2.4.1 and 3.0.0 in SPARK-26267. Please upgrade Spark to higher versions. The other possibility is to upgrade Kafka to 2.3.0 where the Kafka side is fixed."

> "KAFKA-7703 only exists in Kafka 1.1.0 and above, so a possible workaround is using an old version that doesn't have this issue. This doesn't impact Spark 2.3.x and below as we use Kafka 0.10.0.1 by default."

In our case, we faced the same issue on our HDP 3.1 platform. There we have Spark 2.3.2 and the spark-sql-kafka library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78), however, uses kafka-clients 2.0.0. Which means we face this bug due to subsequent conditions:

- Our Spark < 2.4.1
- 1.1.0 < Our Kafka < 2.3.0

### possible work-around solution

We were able to "solve" this issue by removing the checkpoint file in the "offset" sub-folder of the batch number that contains the `0` offset.

When deleting this one file make sure that the batch number in the checkpoint files in sub-folders "commits" and "offset" still match after the deletion.

This is by far not an ideal solution, especially for production environments. However, it might help if you can't update your libraries easily.